# Code Review em tempo de compilação

Tags: delphi, compilação, jenkins, sonarqube

Preciso fazer um Code Review automático nos meus códigos.
Utilizamos o `Jenkins` que dispara a compilação com algumas outras validações todos os dias, mas em horários não comerciais.

Como o projeto é muito extenso e sofre alterações constantes durante o dia, fica inviável disparar o `Job` do `Jenkins` por `commit`.

Sendo assim gostaria de saber se é possível desenvolver um componente de analise de código que valide o código durante a compilação do projeto no `Delphi`.

Dei uma pesquisada sobre como fazer essa validações em tempo de compilação.
Uma das opções que encontrei seria estendendo o compilador do `Delphi`.
Encontrei [este cara](https://github.com/ahausladen/DLangExtensions) mas vi que ele está parado a 1 ano.

Não sei se essa é a unica opção, então gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso de outras formas.

PS: O que preciso fazer são algumas validações semelhante ao `CodeSmells` do `Sonar` no código durante a compilação.

Ex.: Impedir que sejam declarados construtores sem inherited.

Comment: Zanella, dê um exemplo de validação que precisa faze durante a compilação, pois poderíamos resolver de outra forma.

Comment: @David, as validações que preciso, seriam aquelas que o Sonar identifica como Code Smells, acabei de editar a pergunta com uma delas.

Comment: Ahhh entendi, ser mais proativo do que reativo ! Boa, mas não conheço, vamos aguardar :)

Comment: Qual versão do Delphi ?

Comment: @David, 10 Seattle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar uma ferramenta de análise estática de código, como o [Pascal Expert](http://www.peganza.com/products_pex.html)/[Pascal Analyzer](http://www.peganza.com/products_pal.html) da Peganza ou o [FixInsight](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/fixinsight.asp) da TMS por exemplo, para revisar o seu código  antes de fazer o commit.

Essas ferramentas também podem ser integradas via linha de comando, em um job no Jenkins ou em um evento de build nas configurações de projeto do Delphi, para revisar o código após cada commit ou cada build respectivamente.

Comment: Olá, esse TMS FixInsight parece fazer o que preciso, mas só a versão Pro. Vou ver se consigo testa-la para ver, mas a minha intenção é criar uma ferramenta própria para fazer o que o TMS FixInsight Pro faz.

Comment: o TMS FixInsight Pro funcionou legal. o Interessante dele, é que ele consegue fazer uma validação por unit. Com isso eu posso colocar uma validação no "before-commit". Vou testar outras ferramentas gratuitas, até mesmo o Sonar para ver se consigo fazer a mesma coisa. Se não consegui, masco essa resposta como válida.

Comment: Não era bem o que eu queria, mas foi uma solução alternativa para meu caso. Valeu

Comment: @VictorZanella compensa mais fazer a validação no after build, porque o compilador vai ser sempre mais rápido pra avaliar o código do que qualquer analisador e, se tiver algum erro no fonte, não vai adiantar nada fazer a análise do código.

Comment: e tem como fazer essa validação junto com o build do projeto?

Comment: Sim, é só chamar colocar uma linha de comando, pra executar a ferramenta, no after build das configurações do projeto.

Comment: fazendo a revisão por comando, o resultado é cuspido em um arquivo. Sabe se tem como fazer essa validação, e jogar o resultado no "Messages" do Delphi ? (Como se eu fosse em: Project > Run FixInsight)

Comment: Apenas para complementar. Não tem como faze ruma validação interna com ele, em tempo de compilação por linha de comando.

Comment: @VictorZanella tem como fazer antes da compilação e acredito que até mesmo após a compilação usando OTA (Open Tools Api) do delphi. Da uma olhada neste plugin de AutoSave http://www.dummzeuch.de/delphi/autosave/english.html nele temos a implementação usando o OnBeforeCompile com isso você consegue executar o analisador antes da compilação e dependendo os recursos que o FixInsight disponibilize para leitura do output de analise dele você consegue até mesmo mostrar isso em um dialog customizado na IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Vou colocar como resposta pois não coube no comentário.

Geralmente em java uso Jenkins + [Sonarqube](https://sonarqube.org/) (conhecido como Sonar) para avaliação de códigos em geral.

Uma rápida pesquisa no google sobre jenkins + delphi dá para encontrar 2 ou 3 plugins diferentes, todos aparentemente parados em seus respectivos repositórios ...

https://github.com/ahausladen/DLangExtensions

https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/sonar-delphi

temos um plugin também não continuado que é mencionado em uma documentação antiga do sonar:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Delphi+Plugin

Se você tem sua ferramenta preferida de avaliação de código, você poderia criar uma tarefa de pré build ou post build no jenkins e chamar esta sua ferramenta por linha de comando. Após a avaliação, fazer uma asserção de uma determinada métrica a seu respectivo gosto (ex: procurar em um arquivo de texto gerado pela ferramenta por alguma variável).

Outra alternativa, seria você escrever um [plugin para o sonar](https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/sonarqube-plugins-1/).

Comment: O problema é que eu queria algo que fosse disparado na compilação do Delphi, e não um plugin externo, onde eu passo para ele o meu projeto, e ele valida (Sonarqube).